# How to group multiple conditions in an if statement in fish

Tags: fish

As is, the code below is invalid, because the brackets can not be used like that. if we remove them, it runs fine, and outputs:

```
true
true
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

if ( false ; and true ) ; or true
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
end

if false ; and ( true ; or true )
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
end
```

How to get the functionality indicated by the brackets?

desired output:

```
true
false
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`begin`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/begin.html) and [`end`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/end.html) for conditionals as well:

From [fish tutorial](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_conditionals):

> For even more complex conditions, use begin and end to group parts of them.

For a simpler example, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901994/2768231) from stackoverflow.

For your code, you just have to replace the `(` with `begin ;` and the `)` with `; end`.

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

if begin ; false ; and true ; end ; or true
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
end

if false; and begin ; true ; or true ; end
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

***Alternative solution***: **outsource part of the conditional chain into a function**

like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish

function _my_and_checker
    return $argv[1]; and argv[2]
end
function _my_or_checker
    return $argv[1]; or argv[2]
end

if _my_and_checker false true ; or true
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
end

if false; and _my_or_checker true true
    echo "true"
else
    echo "false"
end
```

This makes most sense if the conditions themselves are complex commands.